# Create new lists with del function

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And I want to create a function Delete where it would print to a new list the lists
`['a', 'b']`, `['b', 'c']` and `['a', 'c']`.

My main goal here is designing a function that would return a set of lists consisting of the main list without an element of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is all combinations of length `n-1` where `n` is the length of your list.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> map(list, combinations(a, len(a)-1))
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```

This will give you a list of lists.
Note that a set of lists which you requested is not possible  because lists are not hashable.